# what's ops from tensorflow.python.framework for?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm new to tensorflow, what exactly is the ops imported from tensorflow.python.framework do?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This import statement imports the [`tensorflow.python.framework.ops`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a4b390bffbcb01d8f57f25c007277d457f752a69/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py) module, which (at present) includes the implementations of classes like [`tf.Graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph), [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor), and [`tf.Operation`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Operation).

Note that the `tensorflow.python.framework.ops` module itself is not part of TensorFlow's public API: the precise contents of that module may vary from one version to the next, and you should not depend on it in your code. Instead, you should use `import tensorflow as tf` and access members of that module as (for example) `tf.Graph` instead of `ops.Graph`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! May I ask you again since we can depend on tensorflow API, why I see so many cases people using tensorflow.python.framework.ops, is there any specific purpose?

Comment: I suspect the code has been copy-pasted from a common source (perhaps part of the TensorFlow codebase itself, where we can’t use the public API because it would create a circular dependency). There’s no specific purpose I can think of, and it risks breaking your code from one version to the next.